# How to know DB size using backup file without restoring it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, database-size

Is there anyway so that we can estimated/know size of database using backup file without restoring it?

Comment: What database are you using (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)?  What sort of backup do you have?  For some types of backups the size of the backup is going to be roughly equivalent to the size of the restored database.

Comment: Apologies.. I should have mentioned it earlier.. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, I am trying to fetch this info from a full backup

Comment: Do you use compression of backup?

Comment: @levitologista Not sure how that's relevant - the size of a compressed backup (or an uncompressed backup) may or may not have any bearing whatsoever on the actual size of the data files, because they could be any % full (and a backup only backs up pages with data on them). The only thing the compressed backup size will tell you is that your database is *at least* that big.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is, though you got to use `RESTORE` command anyway. Instead of `RESTORE DATABASE`, use `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` to get a [detailed view of files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in the backup. The Size column tells the file size in bytes.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'v:\MyBackup.bak'
```